# Firefox hides tables with no content and no set height

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, css-tables

I have an empty `table` or `div` with `display:table`:

If I now add a border to the table - even though there is no content - I would expect to see the border.

In Chrome and IE there is a border. In Firefox - the border takes up space, but it is hidden.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0uddvL3x/3/)

```css
table,
div {
  width: 200px;
  background: tomato;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div + div,
table + table {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}
div {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>

<table></table>
<table></table>
```

Similarly, I can even add a `min-height` to the table - Chrome and IE both respect the min-height property, but Firefox still hides the table completely.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0uddvL3x/2/)

So in order for the table to get height in Firefox - the table needs either content or [a set height](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0uddvL3x/4/).

So I'm wondering: Is this a firefox bug, or is there a valid reason/source from the spec that a table with no content or set height is hidden.

Comment: I would tend to assume that it is related to this bug [With empty <tbody>, only top border in fully-bordered table is displayed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1023761) similar to [Bootstrap Issue #13453: table-bordered with tbody and no content = no border](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13453) you could use `table:before{content:"";}`  to force the rendering without setting a height.

Comment: Does this behavior also occur when you put the required elements within the table, like a row and an empty cell or heading?

Comment: @Reinier Kaper: No, but the problem is that they're not required. An empty table is valid, even if it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround for this bug would be to use [CSS generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) on the elements. Even setting an empty string solves the issue, and since it is blank, there should be no negative effects from doing this.

### Workaround:

```
table:after,
div:after {
    content: "";
}
```

### Working Example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ypzaLLb/)):

```css
table, div {
   width: 200px;
   background: tomato;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   border: 2px solid black;
}
div + div, table + table {
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
}

div {   
    display:table;    
}
table:after,
div:after {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>

<table></table>
<table></table>
```

Note that in the example above the default `border-spacing: 2px;` for `table` elements will still be rendered. You can use `border-spacing: 0;` to remove the extra spacing.

On the issue of `min-height` not working, the effects of `min-height` and `max-height` is undefined for `tables`.

### [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights):

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

There's also not much reason to use it, since specifying a `height` does not limit the height of a table, and effectively behaved as `min-height` would.

Comment: It seems to cause the <table> element to have a non-zero height, but not the <div>. I'm not sure why this is the case. Maybe a <tbody>? But AFAIK <tbody> is only generated when there are misparented <tr> elements, not a pseudo-element.

Comment: @BoltClock It is coming from the default `border-spacing: 2px;` for `table` elements in the user-agent stylesheet. The `div` tag does not have this.

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately, 17.6.1 does not appear to say anything about how border-spacing should behave in tables with no rows or cells.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `table, div` to `height: 0;` does the trick for me, yea strange stuff but if it doesn't need any content this should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Highlighting the empty elements in the inspector reveals that the empty table boxes are being rendered with a used height that is equal to `-(border-top-width + border-bottom-width)`. The sheer absurdity of this behavior basically confirms it as a bug, but if you absolutely need a reference, the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout) says:

> The height of a table is given by the 'height' property for the 'table' or 'inline-table' element. A value of 'auto' means that the height is the sum of the row heights plus any cell spacing or borders.

As you can see, it says "plus" borders. Not "minus".

Note that the boxes are indeed there, as they still have margins. They're just being rendered with a negative height for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have noted, Firefox does not allow `min-height` on elements using `display: table` style. Hence it is recommended to change the `min-height` to `height` and it should work. I referred to this [Bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307866)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the height, FF doesn't set automatically the height if isn't define so he knows that they are 2px + 2px of borders and he removed it by set height to -4px, as you can see on computed inspector:
[image]

But Chrome understand that they are no height so he set at 0:

[image]

Welcome to the difference between browsers renders!

Answer (score 0):

Specifying **height** will fulfill your need.